# How to manage files with same name in Wix?

Tags: wix, wix3.5

I have some dll compiled either in .Net3.5 or in .Net4.0. (They have the same name)
In wix, I have 2 conditionals features.
Feature A installs .net3.5 dll of my app with ComponentRef Id="Cmp35"
Feature B installs .net4.0 dll with ComponentRef Id="Cmp40"
Features are mutually exclusives, only one feature is installed.

my components:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">  
    <Fragment>  
        <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">  
            <Component Id="Cmp35" Guid="..">  
                <File Id="Behaviors.Assembly" Name="$(var.Behaviors.v3.5.gen.TargetFileName)" Source="$(var.Behaviors.v3.5.gen.TargetPath)" />  
               <File Id="Other.Assembly" Name="$(var.Other.v3.5.gen.TargetFileName)" Source="$(var.Other.v3.5.gen.TargetPath)" />  
           </Component>  
           <Component Id="Cmp40" Guid="...">  
               <File Id="Behaviors.Assembly.4.0" Name="$(var.Behaviors.v4.0.gen.TargetFileName)" Source="$(var.Behaviors.v4.0.gen.TargetPath)" />  
               <File Id="Other.Assembly.4.0" Name="$(var.Other.v4.0.gen.TargetFileName)" Source="$(var.Other.v4.0.gen.TargetPath)" />  
           </Component>  
       </DirectoryRef>  
    </Fragment>  
</Wix>
```

I have an error during the compilation:
error LGHT0204: ICE30: The target file ... is installed in ... by two different components on an LFN system:
It seems I have an issue because the filenames are the same...
Is there a way to manage this? thanks!

Comment: I do the same, the only difference I have is that in my components I have conditions. Would this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are just warnings from ICE30. If you verified that the Components are truly mutually exclusive then you can ignore the warnings because you did what they told you to. :)

Comment: Thanks Rob! and keep going with your excellent work on Wix ;-)

Comment: I've worked on some really big installers and ignoring even warnings was problematic  because it's hard to know when you have a false positive or a real issue.  We were real sticklers with validation.

Answer (score 5):

I typically get around ICE30 warnings by installing the files to different subdirectories and then using a CopyFile element (DuplicateFile table) to clone the file to the desired directory.  This works well when your features or components are mutually exclusive and you want ICE to be quiet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Christopher. I keep this idea in mind.